# Setting up ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm completely new to ELK and trying to install the stack with some beats for our servers.

Elasticsearch, Kibana and Logstash are all installed (on server A). I followed this guide here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/current/installing-elastic-stack.html.

Filebeat template was installed as well.

I also installed filebeat on another server (server B), and was trying to test the connection

```
$ /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat test output -c 
/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat - 
path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs 
/var/log/filebeat
logstash: my-own-domain:5044...
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... OK
    addresses: 163.172.167.147
    dial up... OK
  TLS...
    security: server's certificate chain verification is enabled
    handshake... OK
    TLS version: TLSv1.2
    dial up... OK
  talk to server... OK
```

Things seems to be ok, yet data from filebeat on server B doesn't seem to be sending data to logstash.

Accessing Kibana keeps redirecting me back to Create Index pattern, with the message

```
Couldn't find any Elasticsearch data
```

Any direction pointing would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer of @NicolasY as accepted, since that solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can you check your `filebeat.yml` file and see if configuration for logs are activated :

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicolasY, that works. Why didn't I notice it haha, was following the guide and it didn't mention this :v

Comment: I was happy to help you ;) !